# Annoying unnecessary overflow and margin-top/bottom doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on  a personal website for a class project. I've come across some bugs in it that I can't seem to get fixed. You can find the website at [bnb.im](http://bnb.im) or at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bnb/pen/JAsyC) (the codepen is mostly copy and paste; I did the best I could with it).

So, the first problem is the white space to the right of the screen. I can't tell what's causing it--when I use the Select element feature on FF, it just selects `<html>`. I asked on another site, and someone said that it was caused by the animation of the portfolio items sliding in--I tried the fix they suggested, adding `overflow: hidden;` to `body`, but it didn't work (the page became unscrollable). I also tried making the portfolio items smaller (45% instead of 50%), but that didn't help, either. Any ideas?

The second problem is with the portfolio items and/or the social section. Whenever I try to add `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` to put some white space between the last portfolio item and the social section, nothing happens for the most part. The only time I've gotten it to work is when I put the margin-top on the social section to 200%, but it was too much so that won't work. Any ideas with this one?

Thanks a lot--I really appreciate you taking the time to read through this and (hopefully!) look at my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem looks fixed to me? Did you figure it out?

The second one take off `height:100%;`from `.portfolio`

Comment: My previous comment disappeared. Maybe I closed the tab or something. Anyway, the first problem you've got to scroll right to see the whitespace. You can use middle click and move your cursor right or drag the scrollbar at the bottom of the screen. It's still there for me. Removing `height: 100%;` fixed the second one, though. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes I see, add `overflow: hidden;` to `html` - should fix it uo

Comment: Doing that completely nullifies the ability to scroll on FF, unless you middle click. I just remembered that there are `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` properties--using `overflow-x: hidden;` does the job on Firefox.

Comment: Great - so sorted? If my help answered your question, could you mark this question answered? Happy coding!